# UITableView footer's Position

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I was trying to make a view that users insert their profile, and I made it. but there's a problem I have.

[image: screenshot]

Footer text doesn't stick at the top of the footer, so I was looking for the solution but I couldn't find anywhere to fix it.

I want to arrange footer text like this image

[image: design image]

what should I do?

code of `titleForFooterInSection`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForFooterInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if section <= 1{
        return "5~15자로 작성해주세요"
    }else{
        return nil
    }
}
```

+++ code of `heightForFooterInSection`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    switch section {
    case 0:
        return 44
    case 1:
        return 64
    default:
        return 0
    }
}
```

I wonder even this can make an issue like this.

Comment: Did you override heightForFooterInSection method?

Comment: Yes, I did. Can even it make an issue like this?

Comment: @CyanLee Paste your code in `heightForFooterInSection `

Comment: @sunkehappy did it.

Comment: It doesnt look like footer, but header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, the title is just vertically center aligned. So if you want to align it to top, you need to create a custom footer. Code may like bellow. You should adjust for your case.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

    let label = UILabel()
    // Note here you should use AutoLayout instead of the frame.
    // You may consider using SnapKit.
    label.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 8, width: 100, height: 10)

    if section <= 1 {
        label.text = "5~15자로 작성해주세요"
    }
    view.addSubview(label)
    return view
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    switch section {
    case 0:
        return 44
    case 1:
        return 64
    default:
        return 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! I didn't notice that footer title is vertically aligned.